# Only target posts and not pages when using the_content() PHP function with WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having trouble changing the posts display in my WordPress website. So far, the posts can display a title and text content, and I would like to display tags, categories and an image. I added the following code in *functions.php* and it actually displays the p tags, but around the content, and not in it. Also, it is displayed on all pages of my website, while I just want to add these HTML tags inside the posts.

So,

- How can I put the tags inside the_content() and only display the custom HTML in posts?

I hope my question is clear, I starting learning PHP a few days ago, sorry!

Thank you so much in advance for you help!

The code :

```
// Creating a custom function that appends HTML to the content

function bts_add_html_to_content( $content ) {
    $html_segment = '<p>Text to be added.</p>';
    $content = $html_segment . $content . $html_segment;
    return $content;
  }
  add_filter( 'the_content', 'bts_add_html_to_content', 99);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure what you want for the "in it" part but I can help with conditionally applying your code to posts only... See below:

```
// Creating a custom function that appends HTML to the content

function bts_add_html_to_content( $content ) {
    // if not a post then return the $content as is
    if ('post' !== get_post_type()) {
        return $content;
    }

    // must be a post if we get here so lets do something with it
    $html_segment = '<p>Text to be added.</p>';
    $content = $html_segment . $content . $html_segment;
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'bts_add_html_to_content', 99);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps a lot, It's only showing on posts now :) I'm actually trying to link form inputs to posts so that users can post not only text but also images and tags ect. If you have any advices on that, please share :) Thank you again!